# Source highlight as CGI script

Tags: web-development, server-side-scripting

I would like to put syntax-highlighted source code (C) on a website using CGI. I have the GNU source-highlight package on the web-server. Can anyone tell me how to link the source-highlight-cgi script (shell script, not perl) into CGI.

I guess I need a perl script in the cgi-bin to point somehow at the source-highlight-cgi shell script I but have no experience of doing this.

Note: CGI is enabled and working on the server.

Comment: You just have to put that script into the cgi-bin directory and make it executable. What I can't tell you is how you specify the source file that needs highlighting via the URL. You may need to dive into the source to work out how do that.

Comment: There is a comment in the script (bourn shell, not perl) saying "This wrapper script should never be moved out of the build directory.  If it is, it will not operate correctly.", so I need to call it from cgi-bin

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

> ## Running scripts outside of the cgi-bin
>
> ### Overview
>
> This article describes how to execute scripts outside of your cgi-bin
>   using a `.htaccess` file.
>
> You will be able to execute CGI scripts outside of your cgi-bin.
>   Enabling this in a web-accessible directory is slightly more insecure
>   than limiting script execution to the cgi-bin, because if a malicious
>   script is ever uploaded to your server, it will be more easily able to
>   be executed.
>
> ### Requirements
>
> Before you start, you'll need:
>
> - FTP login credentials and a plain text editor or SSH enabled and vi    knowledge.
>
> ### Instructions
>
> Add the following lines to your `.htaccess` file:
>
> ```
> Filename: .htaccess
>
> AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
>
> Options +ExecCGI
> ```
>
> Then, upload the `.htaccess file` to the directory in which you want
>   to enable CGI script execution, via FTP. For more information on
>   creating and uploading `.htaccess` files, please see: [Using .htaccess
>   files](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1658/#gs).
>
> *NOTE:*
>
> You can add any file extension to the AddHandler line in your
>   `.htaccess` file. The example is for CGI and Perl scripts.
>
> If you are using this directive in your existing cgi-bin directory,
>   the above line alone will also work.

Source: [Running scripts outside of the cgi-bin](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/30/Running+scripts+outside+of+the+cgi-bin)

Comment: Thanks, it probably does. I've actually forgotten why I wanted to do that now, but if I ever need to in future, I'll know where to look :-)